# Has Many relationship undefined in computed relationship Cannot read property 'reject' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given that I have the following

Model

```
var Artistecontract = ErrorManaged.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  signatoryEmail: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.attr('string'),
  engagements: DS.hasMany('engagement', { async: true }),
  artisteproject: DS.belongsTo('artisteproject', { async: true }),
});
```

Controller

```
var ArtistecontractEngagementsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  availableEngagements: function () {
    var engagements = this.get('engagements');
    return this.get('artisteproject.engagements').reject(function (engagement) {
      return engagements.contains(engagement)
    });
  }.property('artisteproject.engagements', 'engagements')
});
```

Route

```
var ArtistecontractEngagementRoute = AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('artistecontract', params.id);
  },
  actions: {
    include: function (artisteproject, engagement) {
      artisteproject.get('engagements').then(function (engagements) {
        engagements.pushObject(engagement);
        artisteproject.save();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

When I access the availableEngagements attribute I then receive

```
Cannot read property 'reject' of undefined
```

What I want to do Is get a array of engagements from the artisteproject that aren't already in the engagements attribute.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the engagements part of the contract promise

```
  _this.store.find('artistecontract', _this.get('id')).then(function (artistecontract) {
    return Ember.RSVP.all([
      artistecontract.get('engagements'),
      artistecontract.get('artisteproject')
    ]).then(function(){
      return artistecontract;
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `.reject` on `this.get('artisteproject.engagements')`, but the error message is telling you `this.get('artisteproject.engagements')` is undefined, meaning either

1. `this.get('artisteproject')` is undefined, or
2. `this.get('artisteproject.engagements')` is undefined.

Based on the code you posted, you never defined an `artisteproject` property on the controller. In Ember, whatever you return from the `model` hook of a route gets set as the `model` property of the associated controller. So, in your controller code, try this instead:

```
this.get('model.engagements').reject...
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I pass either this.get('artisteproject') or
this.get('artisteproject.engagements') 
to the view they are indeed defined.
I tried model. as well no luck :(

Comment: add a `debugger` right before those lines, and see what they evaluate to.